# python mysql: connection cursor has no execute attribute

Tags: python, mysql-python

while trying out some mysql voodoo, the follwing error pops up. i read
other questions here and the suggestions were to use a cursor for the connection which i already have done imho. so what could be wrong here?

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

    import os
    import sys
    import MySQLdb as db
    try:
        import json
        from json import JSONDecodeError
    except ImportError:
        import simplejson as json
        from simplejson import JSONDecodeError

    connections = {
        'conn1': db.connect('nimmsag_a', 'aix_regread', 'cmdbuser', 'aix_registry'),
        'conn2': db.connect('localhost', 'ansible', 'ansible', 'ansible_inv')
    }

    connections['conn1'].cursor.execute('SELECT * FROM TABLES;')
    connections['conn2'].cursor.execute('SELECT * FROM TABLES;')

    [conn.close() for key, conn in connections.items()]

root@lpgaixmgmtlx01:/root>./reg2inv.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./reg2inv.py", line 18, in <module>
    connections['conn1'].cursor.execute('SELECT * FROM TABLES;')
AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'execute'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[As documented](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0249/#cursor) - and spelled in all letters in the traceback - `connection.cursor` is a function that returns a `Cursor` object. You must first get a cursor by calling `connection.cursor()`, *then* execute your queries:

```
c1 = connections['conn1'].cursor()
c1.execute('SELECT * FROM TABLES')
```

Comment: connections['conn1'].cursor().execute('SELECT * FROM nodes;')
connections['conn2'].cursor().execute('SELECT * FROM host;') seems to work

Comment: Usually you want to keep a reference on the cursor so you can get your query results ;)